# Reset original value about:config firefox via javascript or imacros

Tags: javascript, firefox, reset, imacros

I need to reset value in Firefox *about:config* with Javascript or imacros.

I found Javascript code that is compatible with imacros to set value in *about:config* via Javascript.

To set the value in *about:config* I use this code:

```
iimPlayCode("URL GOTO=about:config\n WAIT SECONDS=1"); 
var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
prefs.setBoolPref("pdfjs.disabled", true);
prefs.setIntPref("browser.download.folderList", 2);
prefs.setCharPref("browser.download.dir", "C:\\");
```

Now I want to know if there exists a similar solution to reset the value to return with original values.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is this

> var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
>   prefs.clearUserPref("layout.css.devPixelsPerPx");

prefs.clearUserPref is the code to reset firefox about:config value change "layout.css.devPixelsPerPx" with the voice to reset.

Answer (score 1):

Let me describe the idea below:

```
// This part is unnecessary
// iimPlayCode("URL GOTO=about:config\n WAIT SECONDS=1");

var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
var originalValue = prefs.getCharPref("browser.download.dir");
prefs.setCharPref("browser.download.dir", "C:\\");

// do something useful here

prefs.setCharPref("browser.download.dir", originalValue);
```

Hope my code is clear enough.

Comment: This solution don't solve the problem because to set some value in about:config necessary to add a string and to be return to original value need to be reset this value. This is an example: to edit oscpu on firefox must use this command prefs.setCharPref("general.oscpu.override", "Linux"); but to remove this customization is necessary to reset "general.oscpu.override" and after restarting firefox "general.oscpu.override" wll be deleted automatically from firefox and the settings return with original values. With prefs.setCharPref you can add/edit value but not reset value. Thanks for your idea

Comment: I tryed to edit the value with a blank value example prefs.setCharPref("general.oscpu.override", ""); but this do not reset the value and after restarting firefox do not remove the value "general.oscpu.override" and remain setted cpu without value "" not with original default value extracted from the pc. Some values in about:config will be calculate automatically and can edit adding string like "general.oscpu.override" and to return original value need to reset and the the "override" string added.